# Modify values of selected option ANTD

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-table

I want to choose "% Percent" as option, but the value on the select label want to be only "%", if I set value attribute, it doesn't change when select other option

```
Cell: (props) => {
  return (
    <Select
      labelInValue
      style={{ width: "120px", fontSize: "11.25px" }}
      bordered={false}
      // placeholder="Select a person"
      // defaultValue="%"
      // value={setBerArt === "P" ? "P" : "%"}
      onSelect={(value) => {
        console.log(value);
        setBerArt = value.label.split(" ");
        console.log(setBerArt[0]);
      }}
    >
      <Option className={styles.KondArt} value="% Prozentual">
        % Prozentual
      </Option>
      <Option className={styles.KondArt} value="P Pauschalbetrag " text="P">
        P Pauschalbetrag
      </Option>
    </Select>
  );
},
```

Comment: If i understand your question properly, you want to change the `value` in Select when you select any option. `value={setBerArt === "P" ? "P" : "%"}`
You can use a state to handle this. `setBerArt` is just a variable (don't know where you create it but are just using in onSelect and value attribute). When you use a state, and something changes it will render the component then you have the latest value in Select `value` attribute

Comment: It crossed my mind but didn't know how to use hooks on the inside of react-table columns constante, but now that you mentioned I found that I can define state inside Cell. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Cell: (props) => {
  const [berArt, setBerArt] = useState("%");

  return (
    <Select
      labelInValue
      style={{ width: "120px", fontSize: "11.25px" }}
      bordered={false}
      defaultValue="% Prozentual"
      value={berArt}
      onSelect={(value) => {
        setBerArt(value.label.split(" ")[0]);
      }}
    >
      <Option className={styles.KondArt} value="% Prozentual">
        % Prozentual
      </Option>
      <Option className={styles.KondArt} value="P Pauschalbetrag " text="P">
        P Pauschalbetrag
      </Option>
    </Select>
  );
},
```